# What's the difference between getOriginalUrl() and getUrl() in Android WebView?

Tags: android

I read the Android Ref, but still don't know.
Is it diffrent?

I am using getOriginalUrl() in my code:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (webView.getOriginalUrl().equalsIgnoreCase(URL) || webView.getOriginalUrl().equalsIgnoreCase(URL+"?id=id")) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }else if(webView.canGoBack()){
        webView.goBack();
    }else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> from the **[Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebHistoryItem.html)**

### getOriginalUrl()

Returns the original url of this history item. This was the requested url, the final url may be different as there might have been redirects while loading the site.

### getUrl()

Returns the url of this history item. The url is the base url of this history item.

**...**

If the site requested redirects you to another site, `getOriginalUrl();` will return that site url
while `getUrl();` returns the base url you requested, not the **final**
which final means the last site you're in now.